# User Access/Control for Apex Application

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle Apex Application that I'll be launching soon but I need to have the ability to have users create their profile at sign in or I can do it on my end and just set the necessary roles/views.

This is my first application so I have no clue. Someone had mentioned that I'd have to create another Table to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes - a table might / should be involved.

Modify login page so that it contains "Register" button which will lead user to a **public** form page - which isn't based on any table or view! You certainly wouldn't want anyone to be able to **query** existing data and see other users' info!

That form page would contain columns as first and last name, e-mail address (which would be used as application **username** as it is guaranteed **unique**) and desired password. The Submit button would call a **process** which calls stored procedure and passes form items as parameters.

Don't forget to verify data (create **validation** on page), e.g. to make sure that user with that e-mail address doesn't already exist and whatever else you want.

Stored procedure would then **insert** row into the `users` table (I'd suggest you to encrypt password; it will be unreadable so - in another iteration - create the "Forgot your password?" functionality so that you could e-mail a new password to such users).

It also means that you'd create **custom authentication scheme** (read about it in documentation). It requires a function which accepts two parameters (`p_username` and `p_password`) and returns Boolean True value if that combination exists in table (or False if you'll reject login).

That's - more or less - it.